# ID cannot be null (Auto Increment)

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, auto-increment

I'm using an INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY statement for my website. It's for creating news items, so I figured I could use the same MySQL command for both creating and updating news items.

However, when I use the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,title,content) VALUES(NULL,"Test","Test");
```

Instead of creating a new auto increment value it throws an error. However, the command works on my main development server. But not on my laptop. Both versions of MySQL are the same, the only difference being MySQL was installed manually on my server, and with WAMP on my laptop.

Are there any MySQL Variables that could be causing this?

Comment: Do you get the same results when you enter the query via mysql command line client?

Comment: It worked fine in the console. Quadruple checking my PHP code now, expecting the moment where I look like an idiot to arrive imminently.

Comment: Please post a relevant excerpt of your PHP code. You might be doing something like
`<?php $id = NULL; mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id,title,content) VALUES($id,\"Test\",\"Test\""); ?>`
which is *not* the same as 
`<?php mysql_query(..."VALUES(NULL,\"Test\",\"Test\");` ?>

Comment: Found the cause. Auto Increment working fine, it was another column causing the problem. The way the table works is that they have a unique ID but they also have a category id and an index. The index tells the site to display the news in that order for each category, but I was trying to do a manual increment by selecting the highest index for that category and adding 1. However, if no news items existed for that category it would return nothing and I can't have null for that column. I guess I'll have to check manually in my PHP code and add it manually.

Comment: @THeK please answer your own answer then and accept it. Also help to provide more background in the original question so that future people get a better understanding of what went down. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it as best as I can.

I checked my code and found that when I inserted the empty POST'd ID was wrapping it in quotations. I've now changed it so that it puts NULL without quotations. So my query should now look like:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,title,content) VALUES(NULL,"test","Test")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title=VALUES(title), content=VALUES(content);
```

That now works.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `INSERT INTO table (title,content) VALUES("Test","Test");`

This will create a new row in the table with a new incremented ID.

Comment: It would work, however, it would mean in my PHP I would need to add extra code to see if an ID was sent, and write two different SQL commands. Whereas with this, if I could just send a null id if one wasn't given then SQL can do all the work.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Please answer Jack's first question (the comment to your original post). Also provide the outcome of just `INSERT INTO table (title,content) VALUES("Test","Test");` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make query like this,

```
INSERT INTO table (title,content) VALUES("Test","Test");
```

If it still doesn't work then check if `id` column is set as auto-increment or not.